# Display image and text above form

Tags: forms, 8, media

I have form built with form api in Drupal 8,
now, i want to show an image and some text description on top of that form, meaning, before the form is rendered, what i can think of is, doing a node_load and then suffix and prefix with the node_load value or entity load,
but my question is, in case i write a function for node_load or entity_load, where would i call the return value of these functions and how ?
i am thinking of something like this :

```
$form['image_div'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<div class="image"><img src="path_to_image" />',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
```

how can i call the path to image here, which is a function return value.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
 $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();    
 $form['image_div'] = array(
 '#prefix' => '<img src="/' . $theme->getPath() .'/images/smile.png">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
```